# Golf me a memory array

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

This challenge is pretty simple: Your task is to draw a schematic of a (simplified) memory array. You will be given two (positive) integers `n,m` and the task is to draw the `n:2^n` decoder connected to the memory array with `d` data lines.

The addressing will be in the order of [gray codes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GrayCode.html), to check if the sequence is correct, see [A014550](https://oeis.org/A014550). For simplicity there are no input ports, write ports etc. On the top of the decoder you need to specify its type (e.g. `2:4`) and you will label the data lines with `d:[d-1],...,d:1,d:0`. If the cray code wouldn't fit the decoder width, you'll need to expand the width, see the last two examples.

### Rules

- Leading whitespaces are not allowed
- Trailing whitespaces are allowed
- At the end of the output there may be one or several newlines
- You can assume the following constraints on the input `0 < n` and `0 < d <= 1e4`
- The output is either printed to the console or you write a function that returns a newline-separated string
- For invalid input the behaviour of your program/function is left undefined

### Test cases

```
n = 1, d = 1

.-----.
| 1:2 |
|     |
|    0|---+
|     |   |   
|     |  .+.  
|     |  | +-+
|     |  `-' |
|    1|---+  |
|     |   |  |
|     |  .+. |
|     |  | +-+
|     |  `-' |
`-----'      |
            d:0
```

---

```
n = 1, d = 10

.-----.
| 1:2 |
|     |
|    0|---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |   |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |   
|     |  .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.  
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|    1|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|     |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|     |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
`-----'      |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            d:9   d:8   d:7   d:6   d:5   d:4   d:3   d:2   d:1   d:0
```

---

```
n = 2, d = 3

.-----.
| 2:4 |
|     |
|   00|---+-----+-----+
|     |   |     |     |   
|     |  .+.   .+.   .+.  
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' |
|   01|---+--(--+--(--+  |
|     |   |  |  |  |  |  |
|     |  .+. | .+. | .+. |
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' |
|   11|---+--(--+--(--+  |
|     |   |  |  |  |  |  |
|     |  .+. | .+. | .+. |
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' |
|   10|---+--(--+--(--+  |
|     |   |  |  |  |  |  |
|     |  .+. | .+. | .+. |
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|     |  `-' | `-' | `-' |
`-----'      |     |     |
            d:2   d:1   d:0
```

---

```
n = 4, d = 5

.------.
| 4:16 |
|      |
|  0000|---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|      |   |     |     |     |     |   
|      |  .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.  
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0001|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0011|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0010|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0110|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0111|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0101|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  0100|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1100|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1101|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1111|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1110|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1010|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1011|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1001|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
|  1000|---+--(--+--(--+--(--+--(--+  |
|      |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|      |  .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. | .+. |
|      |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|      |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
`------'      |     |     |     |     |
             d:4   d:3   d:2   d:1   d:0
```

---

```
n = 1, d = 1024    (output truncated!)

.-----.
| 1:2 |
|     |
|    1|---+-----+----...
|     |   |     |    ...
|     |  .+.   .+.   ...
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ ...
|     |  `-' | `-' | ...
|    0|---+--(--+--(-...
|     |   |  |  |  | ...
|     |  .+. | .+. | ...
|     |  | +-+ | +-+ ...
|     |  `-' | `-' | ...
`-----'      |     | ...
            d:1023d:1022d:1021...
```

---

```
n = 10, d = 1    (output truncated!)

.-----------.
| 10:1024   |
|           |
| 0000000000|---+
|           |   |   
|           |  .+.  
|           |  | +-+
|           |  `-' |
...        ...    ...
```

---

```
n = 12, d = 5    (output truncated!)

.-------------.
| 12:4096     |
|             |
| 000000000000|---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|             |   |     |     |     |     |   
|             |  .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.   .+.  
|             |  | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+ | +-+
|             |  `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' | `-' |
...          ...    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: what specifies the decoders width? From the examples it looks like its the width of the `n:2^n` + 2, but do we need to extend it when the gray node representation wouldn't fit in it (e.g. n=10, len(`10:1024`)+2 = 9, gray node repr length = 10)

Comment: Yes you'd need to extend it in that case, I'll add an example.

Comment: in that case, how should the decoder type be centered/anchored?

Comment: Anchored to the left, but with a space. See examples I added.

Comment: Summing up, the width would be `max(len(n:2^n)+4,len(graycode)+3)`. The decoder name is always separated with one space from the left and the codes are right aligned without spaces.

Answer (score 6):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 185 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
b :2b^:D⁰∑l2+bIΧCc┌*:A .1ΟO@c*┐1Οd5*2+∙ `a '+++;31žƧ01bH{╬⁰1w⁄»Ƨ01*□+}I{∑4⌡@}¹cb-2+3žKOKOād0C{āe{"h}‼Τ─īsgQ⅛&šε╬»‘6n┌eF-¡3**41ž┐c3*∙ceF-*¡³ (*ž61ž┼}+1C}@5*┐+e*+d┌@4*Ο;┼øe∫eκƧd:ΚF6*1ž}+┼
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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,inputs=NCUwQTU_)

Way too long...

Comment: Well it's a fairly complicated pattern compared with other ASCII-art challenges, I think under `200` bytes is quite good. Unfortunately I couldn't test it for `n > 8` but it looks good!

Comment: @BruceForte The sad thing is that 85 of the bytes is just the decoder box..

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>170</s> 157 bytes

```
ＮνＮδＡＸ²νηＡ⪫⟦θ:Ｉη ⟧ωθＡ⌈⟦νＬθ⟧ζ←“ E*lÿxγ∨P3ζgRＵ#@˜R2$⁴⟧”Ｆ⁻δ¹Ｃ±⁶¦⁰↓←|  Ｆ⁻η¹Ｃ⁰¦⁵Ｐ←×⁺+×-⁵δ⸿Ｐ|  ←Ｍ×⁵η↓Ｆδ«Ｐ⁺d:ιＭ⁶←»↑←'-←ζ↑`↑²↑×⁵η.-Ｐ⁺¶θζ↓.↓²Ｐ↓×⁵η←Ｆη«Ｆν←§0110÷ιＸ²κＭν⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZC/SgNBEMZ7n@JAQVAuJP5pUtnYS57AEEGLgGBlYZFtjggWF66IhRJESNQY0Xh3e7lsCOz14zvMC@wjnN/EYLGzy/zm@75lWhfNq9Zls12WznzQQkrszJMzmZ3SgjTe/DbmwZCyujOvpD0ejH5uKRNw1xUA0TtlaFPKQcidB@94p10sr@mbuy8n@5SeN5xJNo/sfWNvi1WMSe48OjNkNafYzpx5tl@sUovGJwcRTG48b831igMITZzBQFj0WeW7Rd9Hh2LOlmhDAeLMRGBCGj5wgP1YNCo/qxOMJojBmJ1z0MO97aPIr3unOHaKspZX/D@ZTSmTgaiCY6er/Og/IpQILRHYgviOqrVatdASJfvLkQigkrI82Dj8BQ) [Verbose approximation.](https://tio.run/##ZVLLTsMwEDzTr1j5wlqxq7aiHMoJwaWIoh6AC0UiNG5jkThp4rQ8vz2skz7S9GTvanZmdux56GfzxI/KcmzSwj4U8bvK0PCrTrMOqL7Oc700OE021BgIMFxAeOjfJdrgy0oAGzEBN35uMSQEA/YqYEO31QE78T91XMT4YgTcK7O0Ia74K2G@CTPNtLE4ulcLS@O/M/ML5/JtZjzpQVV1va47XIFSelLKmWE0uEgywIk2RY6BgD7ncJOkX/iglr5VeEn0PUJNkrXC0W2yMadaAC2esMHTEzB080Vkddqce9SxynEaEZ55bFczydwAqQZ8r8RmGWtxPKvM6rkfuagq@dqgo94VNeHQxS1gZ71yGXD46Zw16GoXgXsC7WTPKoJLGtsS/m35n9KT9c8la/ca7/GUEuSNHTcGx@XWKPk8bNyVrY1ri/Rk7kvscQ0ltyBpdVm7NWhFV3cb6bTTqzIKq4yqq@FwtN61HZtAfSLr9fs98jM29lavdaBQC9h/9A/OqyjvijhFU/@Cv7K86AxLuS5lHv0D) Explanation:

```
ＮνＮδＡＸ²νηＡ⪫⟦θ:Ｉη ⟧ωθＡ⌈⟦νＬθ⟧ζ
```

Sets up the variables used in the rest of the code. `ν` and `δ` are the inputs, `η` is `2`<sup>`ν`</sup>, `θ` is the label at the top of the box, while `ζ` is one less than the width of the box.

```
←“ E*lÿxγ∨P3ζgRＵ#@˜R2$⁴⟧”
```

This compressed string represents the bottom left decoder. This is the one that's most representative, although ironically it first gets printed in the top right and then copied left and down.

```
Ｆ⁻δ¹Ｃ±⁶¦⁰↓←|
```

The decoder is repeated horizontally, and the `--(` at the top right of the last decoder is changed to a `|`.

```
Ｆ⁻η¹Ｃ⁰¦⁵Ｐ←×⁺+×-⁵δ⸿Ｐ|  ←Ｍ×⁵η↓
```

The decoder is then repeated vertically, and the `(`s in the top row are changed to `-`s (if you look carefully you'll see that too many `-`s are printed but fortunately the last one gets overwritten by the `0` of the address), after which the `|`s for the top right decoder are removed.

```
Ｆδ«Ｐ⁺d:ιＭ⁶←»
```

The decoders are numbered right-to-left.

```
↑←'-←ζ↑`↑²↑×⁵η.-Ｐ⁺¶θζ↓.↓²Ｐ↓×⁵η←
```

The box is printed, including the label.

```
Ｆη«Ｆν←§0110÷ιＸ²κＭν⁵
```

The Gray codes are printed.